# How to get max value from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using Sql Server

I want to get max value from two table

Table1

```
ID Total

101 100
102 600
.....
```

Table2

```
ID Total

101 300
102 400
....
```

I want to get a max value from 2 table according to the id

Expected Output

```
ID Total

101 300 (max value in table2)
102 600 (max value in table1)
....
...
```

How to make a Query

Need Query Help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT
   ID, MAX(Total)
FROM
    (
    SELECT ID, Total FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Total FROM Table2
    ) foo
GROUP BY
   ID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
; with
q_00 as (
select id, Total from Tbl_1
union all
select id, Total from Tbl_2
)
select id, max(Total)
from q_00
group by id
order by id ;
```

Answer (score 1):

One other option worth considering might be

```
WITH T(ID, Total)
     AS (SELECT ID,
                MAX(Total)
         FROM   Table1
         GROUP  BY ID
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ID,
                MAX(Total)
         FROM   Table2
         GROUP  BY ID)
SELECT ID,
       MAX(Total) AS Total
FROM   T
GROUP  BY ID
```

If `ID,Total` is indexed in the two tables possibly this might give a better plan (untested)

Comment: Although now tested and the difference between the two is pretty marginal and can be skewed either way by adjusting the number of `Total` rows in each `ID` group.